# Overlay images inside a list

Tags: css

I have this html css so far

```
<html><head><style type="text/css">
.img_list {    
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
}

#img_list .icon {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
li{
list-style:none;
}
</style></head>
<body>
<ul id="img_list">
    <li>
        <img src="images.jpg" alt="Image Title" class="img_list" />
        <img class="icon" src="Arrow.png" alt="You've done XYZ to this." />
        <a>Charlie Chaplin</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="images.jpg" alt="Image Title" class="img_list"/>
        <img class="icon" src="Arrow.png" alt="You've done XYZ to this." />
        <a>Charlie Bean</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the rendered image
![enter image description here][1]

what i wanted was to have the down arrow image to overlay on top of the image itself at the bottom right of each image.
i tried playing with top, bottom, right left but its not consistent with browsers size.
how do i change my css to have this work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `position: relative;` to the list items.

```
li {
list-style:none;
position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting that result because you are positioning the icon relative to the container, `#img_list`. Try adding `position:relative;` to your `li` css definitions, and removing it from the `#img_list{` definitions:

```
li{
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
}
```

**See this live Demo (with replacement images): http://jsfiddle.net/wm4rj/**

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #img_list li {
            list-style:none;
            position:relative;
            line-height:50px;
        }
        #img_list li .img_list {    
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
        }
        #img_list li .icon {
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 99;
            bottom: 20px;
            left:0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="img_list">
        <li>
            <img src="images.jpg" alt="Image Title" class="img_list" />
            <img class="icon" src="Arrow.png" alt="You've done XYZ to this." />
            <a>Charlie Chaplin</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="images.jpg" alt="Image Title" class="img_list"/>
            <img class="icon" src="Arrow.png" alt="You've done XYZ to this." />
            <a>Charlie Bean</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```